# Smell of the methanol

Tags: alcohols, smell

When I first time smell the methanol, for me it was similar to the benzene (completely different from the ethanol). But almost everywhere information says, that it should me very similar to the ethanol. (I am talking about almost dry methanol, not dissolved in water or mixed with ethanol.)

***I understand, that smelling chemicals is not healthy, but kills the dosage, not the poison. The only breath won't kill anybody. (Off-course, if you are working with methanol or other dangerous compounds you must wear gas-mask and/or work with good ventilation!)***

How would you describe the smell of the methanol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a qualitative answer, so you'll get a lot of odd things in these responses.

I find methanol to be like ethanol but shimmed by a plastic/wood-life taste.

More importantly, having a higher volatility, its taste will be more intense because there are more vapors to stimulate your odor receptors which frequently change or augment tastes.

Comment: Yes, the smell is much more intense, than the ethanol.